# Displaying SubQuery on VF Page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

Can anyone help with this

```
notices =[SELECT Description__c,Id,Name__c,Notice_Date__c, (select id,Name from Attachment), FROM Notice__c];
```

I have object notice with attachment

It has one attachment and I want to have out put like this on vf page

Notice Name
Notice Description
Notice Date

Attachment Name or ID associated with that notice record

---

My Controller

```
public class On_StudentNoticeController {
    public List<Notice__c> notices{get;set;}

    public On_StudentNoticeController (){
        notices=new List<Notice__c>();
    }

    public PageReference Onpageload() {
        notices = [SELECT Id,  Name__c, Description__c,Notice_Date__c,
            (SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachments) 
        FROM Notice__c 
        ORDER BY Notice_Date__c DESC NULLS FIRST];
    }
}
```

Screenshot of my current problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit #2**

Looks like you're trying to iterate over empty list. Your order of execution is wrong and you have overcomplicated your life. Although I would say this should be a runtime error and not compilation one, interesting. Maybe the compiler got smarter.

Here's why your code will not work:

1. Constructor (`On_StudentNoticeController ()`) fires. It creates empty list.
2. Page gets rendered, Visualforce will display an empty list.
3. You're calling page action to populate the list of notices but it's too late. They "will be" there when page reloads but it'll be empty initially.

Try like that? I've literally copied code for my custom object with attachments. You should just have to change few object & field names and be good to go:

```java
public class accswithattachments {

    public List<SF_Payable__c> accs {get; private set;}

    public accswithattachments(){
        accs = [SELECT Id, Name, LastModifiedDate, 
            (SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachments)
            FROM SF_Payable__c
            ORDER BY CreatedDate
            LIMIT 1000];
    }
}
```

```xml
<apex:page controller="accswithattachments" >
<ol>
    <apex:repeat value="{!accs}" var="a">
        <li><apex:outputField value="{!a.Name}" /><br/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!a.LastModifiedDate}" /><br/>

            <apex:dataList value="{!a.Attachments}" var="attachment">
               <apex:outputText value="{!attachment.Name}"/>
            </apex:dataList>
            <br/>
        </li>
    </apex:repeat>
</ol>
</apex:page>
```

Output (for my data of course):

[image]

I'm quite curious why it was giving you compilation errors. I think I know why it was complaining (the list was empty). but still...

---

**Edit #1** to answer the comment:

Here's what works for me. It's Account attachments (because I don't have your object). It doesn't even use Apex controller.

```xml
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
<ol>
    <apex:repeat value="{!accounts}" var="acc">
        <li><apex:outputField value="{!acc.Name}" /><br/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Description}" /><br/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!acc.LastModifiedDate}" /><br/>

            <apex:dataList value="{!acc.Attachments}" var="attachment">
               <apex:outputText value="{!attachment.Name}"/>
            </apex:dataList>
            <br/>
        </li>
    </apex:repeat>
</ol>
</apex:page>
```

---

**Original answer**

Your query does not compile, I think it should be something similar to this:

```sql
SELECT Id, Name__c, Description__c,Notice_Date__c,
    (SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachments)
FROM Notice__c
```

Once you get it to work you should read up about Visualforce tags that loop over collections (apex:dataList, apex:dataTable, apex:pageBlockTable, [apex:repeat](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_repeat.htm)...). Use one of them depending on how you want your output to look like

Something like this?

```xml
<apex:repeat value="{!notices}" var="notice">
    <p>
        <apex:outputField value="{!notice.Name__c}" /><br/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!notice.Description__c}" /><br/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!notice.Notice_Date__c}" /><br/>
    </p>
    <apex:dataList value="{!notice.Attachments}" var="attachment">
        <apex:outputText value="{!attachment.Name}"/>
    </apex:dataList>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: It is giving this error
Error: Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Name'

Comment: You didn't copy the example correctly, most likely in the repeater you're referring to whole table of data (say "attachments") instead of one single record that's "current" ("attachment").

Comment: please have a look to this 
this is this the error

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=562EA9727AB16B6B%212601


its working on Accounts object but not on Custom object

Comment: Did you fix your query?

Comment: Yes ..
If i am using {!notice.Attachments} in output text on printing it on VF Page
then its printing id in square backets []

Comment: I've rewritten my example in my dev org to explicitly query for data (instead of using recordSetVar) and it still works. Post your controller, either whole class or just the relevant bits that still reproduce the problem. I want to see that variable has public getter, either something like `public List<Notice__c> notices {get; private set;}` or `public List<Notice__c> getNotices(){ ... }`. Also - are you sure you don't use same word "attachment" anywhere else? Maybe it's confusing the Visualforce compiler into referencing another variable...

Comment: It's a guess but I think you have a publicly visible list variable called "attachment" somewhere in the controller and then when VF page sees `{!attachment}` it doesn't know whether you mean that one or the local variable in the apex:repeat loop. You shouldn't name variables identical to names of standard objects, look how confusing it can be: `Account opportunity = new Account(Name = 'x'); insert opportunity;`

Comment: Updated my controller Please have a look